# Set ADT union Assistance

Tags: java, set

I have been trying for hours to code a union method that will take the contents of two arrays and place it in a third array without duplicates. 
The combined array must be returned without the duplicates

This is what I have got so far. any help will be much appreciated

```
private String Union(){
        String combined = "";
        int pointer =0;
        for(int index = 1; index <=numbers.length; index++)
        {
            for(int contents =0; contents<=pointer; pointer++)
            {
                if(numbers[index]==union[contents])
                {
                    break;
                }
            }//end compare loop

        }//end numbers for loop


        for(int index = 1; index <=ages.length; index++)
        {

        }//end ages for loop


    }//end Union
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain exactly what you want this program to return and what results you are currently getting, as it's not entirely clear from the question and it's vital for understanding your problem.

Comment: I have changed edited the information provided

Comment: What things are you allowed to use? What are you not allowed to use? Where exactly is it that you are stuck, and why?

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is use a Java 8 stream for your two arrays:

```
int[] union = IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(numbers), IntStream.of(ages))
      .distinct()
      .toArray();
```

That's a nice way to solve problems like this.

Comment: We are not allowed to do it that way, it has to be in a method following the rules laid out to use which is similar to the code which I have included above